# Windows Message lparam converting

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

How do I convert a value to the form the same as that of `lparam` in a Windows Message?

```
X := SMALLINT(lParam and $FFFF);
Y := SMALLINT((lParam shr 16) and $FFFF);
```

So lparam convert in Word. How to make a reverse conversion?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `MakeLParam()` function in the `Windows` unit, it will make the code easier to write and understand.

Answer (score 1):

2 word to integer:

```
(Y shl 16) or X;
```